# Errors With Jpanel And Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I am getting an error when I try to use the paint(Graphics g) code. Could you help resolve the code so that there is a window with a 3d rectangle. Thanks!

```
private static void paint(Graphics g){
    g.draw3DRect(10, 10, 50, 50, true);
```

and then towards the botttom:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
            paint();

        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: Paint should be inside createandshow, also what is the error?

Comment: this is the error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method paint(Graphics) in the type main is not applicable for the arguments ()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, the visibility of methods cannot be reduced when overriding. Likewise instance methods cannot be made `static`. It is required to be

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.draw3DRect(10, 10, 50, 50, true);
}
```

In Swing, don't do custom painting in top level windows such as a `JFrame`. 
Instead create a subclass of `JComponent` and override `paintComponent` and make sure to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.

---

```
class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.draw3DRect(10, 10, 50, 50, true);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 300);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add an instance of the new component to the `JFrame`:

```
frame.add(new MyComponent());
```

Comment: How do I do that? Should I extend Jcomponent?

Comment: So do I make that a separate class the to one I already have?

Comment: there is an error with the "g" here javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
                super.paintComponent(g);

Comment: Don't call `paintComponent` directly. Call `repaint` instead. In fact when the application is made visible for the first time, there is no need to even call `repaint`

Comment: but if i dont call it nothing will happen

Comment: No, if I dont call something then it won't happen

Comment: The problem is in the code you're not showing us. Post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) of your code

Comment: You need to add an instance of the new component to your frame